# Creating a view table with reference table and submission table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

So I have two tables:
One table has ID's and field labels, the other table with the form submission data but it shows the IDs referenced from the first table.

[picture of table 1 and table 2 as well as desired joined table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jjb1.png)

I want to make a view that shows the form submission data but with the labels from the first table instead of the ID's associated with it. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can join two tables to get the desired result:

```
CREATE VIEW test_view (Probability) AS 
SELECT t1.label 
from table_1 t1
left join table_2 t2
on t1.id = t2.probability_id;
```

[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=073fe748bbd00ca6ebf61cf8e0a63a8d)

Comment: this would work but the sample i gave was small. The real data im working with has way more columns, meaning i would have to make 20+ tables just to do all that

Comment: I do not understand what you want to say. Please add some example in your question - one more complicated example would be enough. Help us help you. You can imagine how is it hard for me to imagine your problem without any info ?